# How to use a dll compiled with VC++ 2013 with cython?

Tags: python, c++, c, visual-studio, cython

I am developing a library for 3D and environmental audio in C++, which I wish to use from Python and a myriad of other languages.  I wish it to work with Kivy on the iPhone down the line, so I want to use Cython instead of ctypes.  To that end, I have already constructed and exposed a C-only api that uses only primitive types, i.e. no structs.  I would ideally like to have only one implementation of the Python binding, and believe that on Mac/Linux this won't be a problem (I could be wrong, but that is off-topic for this question).

The problem is that it is using C++11 heavily, and consequently needs to compile with VC++ 2013.  Python 2 is still typically compiled with VC++ 2008, and I believe Python 3 is only VC++ 2010.

I am familiar with the rules for dynamic runtime mixing: don't pass memory out and free it from the other side, never ever send handles back and forth, etc.  I am following them.  This means that I'm ctypes and cffi-ready.  All functions are appropriately `extern "c"` and the like.

Can I use this with Cython safely, and if so how?  My reading is giving me very mixed answers on whether or not it's safe to go use the export library produced by VC++ 2013 with VC++ 2008, and Cython seems to have no in-built functionality for dynamically linking (and that won't work on iOS anyway).  The only thing I can think of that would work besides linking with the import library is to also bind the windows DLL manipulation functions and use those in Cython-but this defeats the one implementation goal pretty quickly.

I've already tried researching this myself, but there seems to be no good info; simply trying it will be inconclusive for weeks-linking is no guarantee of functionality, after all.  This is the kind of thing that can very easily seem to work right without actually doing so; to that end, sources and links to further reading are much appreciated.